# TypeScript Property 'name' does not exist on type xxx

Tags: typescript

I just defined a TypeScript class:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    static isAnimal(a) {
        return a instanceof Animal;
    }
}
```

The compiler gave me error:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Animal'.

I find the issue reported on TypeScript [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6373) but it seems there is no resolution yet.

Although there is error message, the complier can still generate proper javascript. But I want to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a class property: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#classes

```js
class Animal {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    static isAnimal(a: any) {
        return a instanceof Animal;
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeAoavrzGQFMAuaCAFwCdF4BzAbixz2AHt5KqBXYCtqgAoCxMl1p0AlJhZ48FABaIIAOhFFoAXnyEiTOQF9mcymAqJg0ZQhRpBYMmHgBPadjlyqRCtyrxoYFacFE7ARGwAZnBIqCD6eEYGQA)

Comment: I understand declare a property can avoid the error.  I just want to learn from the community if the issue which reported on github is resolved or not. I am new to TypeScript. Thank you.